# <div> layout issue with a grid of responsive squares

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a grid of responsive squares over a colored background `<div>`. What am I doing wrong that the `bottombar` `<div>` isn't below the grid of squares and instead inline with the top of the background?

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#squarecontainer, #infoi {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#squarecontainer {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color:yellow;
}

#infoi {
   z-index: 2;
   background-color:blue;
}

.square {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit  */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko         */
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  padding-bottom:50%;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  background-color:#7F3F98;
  /* RGBa with 0.9 opacity */
  background-color: rgba(127, 63, 152, 0.9);
  /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#E67F3F98, endColorstr=#E67F3F98);
  /* For IE 8*/
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#E67F3F98, endColorstr=#E67F3F98)";
  overflow:hidden;
}

.table{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.content {
  position:absolute;
  height:90%;
  width:90%;
  padding: 5%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:160%;
  font-size:5vw;
  color: #fff;
}

#cell4 {
  visibility:hidden;
}

#bottombar {
  clear:both;
  position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="topbar">Topbar information here</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="squarecontainer">
      <div class="square" id="cell1">
        <div class="content">
        Div 1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="square" id="cell2">
        <div class="table">
        <div class="content">
        Div 2
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="square" id="cell3">
        <div class="content">
        Div 3
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="square" id="cell4">
        <div class="content">
        Div 4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infoi">Floating text here</div>
</div>
<div id="bottombar">Bottombar info here</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8o643xqx/7/

Comment: Do you really  need  'position :absolute ;' ?http://jsfiddle.net/8o643xqx/1/

Comment: I'm going to have another `<div>` on top (higher z-index). If I don't use `position: absolute` on the background, that `<div>` won't be positioned properly.

Comment: You should include _all_ relevant code when you're submitting a question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I simplified the code as to reduce its complexity and overlooked that bit. Editing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GCyrillus asked in his comment; Do you really need absolute positioning?

I removed it, and added `overflow: hidden;` to `#squarecontainer`, and everything seems to be working as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/8o643xqx/9/

**EDIT**: Basically the same thing with this one. How's this?

Comment: I posted a comment above and didn't notice you had responded. There's going to be another `<div>` positioned on top of the squares with a higher z-index. Unless I'm mistaken, if I don't use `positon: absolute`, I won't be able to line up the `<div>`s properly. Sorry about forgetting that part when simplifying the code for the question.

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of only using `position:absolute` for the overlay `<div>` instead of both it and the base one.